# Using the MS Graph 'findMeetingTimes' endpoint with client credential (/application) flow

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

So I would like to prevent the usage of delegated user authentication flow but still want to use the `findMeetingTimes` endpoint. But it doesn't seem available for client credential flow, right?

I simply tried to post on this endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/findMeetingTimes
```

But it seems like it doesn't exist. Wrror response message:

```
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'findMeetingTimes'."
```

Is there any workaround for using it with the application flow?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `findMeetingTimes` is not supported for `Application` permission type

Resources:

[findMeetingTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)